# BarChart does not update properly JavaFX-2

Tags: java, javafx-2, bar-chart

I have a BarChart that displays a metric for the number of weeks in a year i.e. a fixed number of 54 bars. I have implemented a slider which zooms on  higher values (up to the last week) and also allows to unzoom back to a larger number of weeks. So you can zoom from a range of 1-54 weeks all the way down to week 54 and then back to any abstract number of weeks.

My problem is that the first "zoom" works but when I zoom out the values on XAxis are reversed and mixed and after that they stay that way.

I clear the barchart using: barchart.getData().clear(); every time the slider is "listened" and I am pretty sure that what I set the BarChar to is correct and in the correct order.

If I apply:

barchart.getXAxis().getTickMarks().clear();

the application works but I obviously get exceptions every time the above line is called. It seems that the barchart keeps some attributes even when cleared.
Any help?

Comment: Can you show an exception here?

Comment: This is what I get: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161) at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
 at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:571)
 at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:234)